# Wildfly: Why I get only "Forbidden" if I call my Web application?

Tags: java, wildfly, wildfly-9

Yesterday our web application ran fine on WildFly 9. Since this morning I get only a "Forbidden" in the web browser. We don't use JAAS. There is also no difference if I set the following value to `false` in the `standalone.xml`:

```
...
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:3.0">
   ...
   <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
   ...
</subsystem>
...
```

What can be the reasons that WildFly only shows the "Forbidden" page?

**EDIT**

If I set the log level for package `org.jboss.security` to `TRACE` I get the following message in the log file while calling the page:

```
2016-01-27 12:58:15,354 TRACE [org.jboss.security] (default task-5) PBOX00354: Setting security roles ThreadLocal: null
```

Not sure what this means ...

Comment: What URI are you hitting and where is your app deployed to?

Comment: @John: The application is deployed from eclipse (by using the JBoss Devel.-Plugin) on a local running WildFly. The URI ist http://127.0.0.1:8080/myApp/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My EAR project and the inherited WAR project in eclipse was broken. There were several things missing like at example the `application.xml`.

Not sure why these things are missing and where I have lost it. But after fixing both projects deployments it works again.

Answer (score 4):

That can occur if you do not have any *index.html* file at the root of the war file *(in WebContent in Eclipse)* or your write it wrongly like: *Index.html*

Same issue if `<welcome-file>` is not properly set up in *WEB-INF/web.xml* descriptor

Answer (score 2):

That build must be corrupted. Re-build the application, create war again and deploy it again. It will work.